# How to change dqpk-query -L <package-name> view?

Tags: string, awk, sed, directory

I use `dpkg-query -L <package-name>` to list all files belong to the specific package.

The result is a lot of files with their directory:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/tree
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tree
/usr/share/doc/tree/TODO
/usr/share/doc/tree/copyright
/usr/share/doc/tree/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/tree/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/tree.1.gz
```

Because the outpu is too many,i always use this command like this:

```
dpkg-query -L tree > tree.txt
```

My question is how to change the view of the list in tree.txt to become more human readable,let the output be sorted by their directory prefix.

The `rpm -ql <package-name>` comand has the same use on Centos.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. The output is already sorted, isn't it?

Comment: @AndriyMakukha sorry,i means the view can be grouped by their directory prefix.I had modify my question.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think the `uniq -w num` can satisfy my need.As i just want to filter the directories end up with the specific application name,so i can go to that directory to see more information,meanwhile don't loss any directory belongs to the specific application.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to have only **/usr/share/doc/tree** as output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the folders:

```
dpkg -L <pkg-name> | xargs -I{} dirname {} | sort -u
```

A version which groups files by directory could be done using a shell function:

```
lspkg() {
    pkg="${1}"
    if [ -t 1 ] ; then
        color_dir=$'\x1b\x5b34;1m'
        color_link=$'\x1b\x5b36m'
        color_end=$'\x1b\x5b0m'
    fi  
    LANG=C dpkg -L "${pkg}" \
      | awk -F: '{printf "%s%s\n",$NF,(NF>1?" (pkg set link)":"")}' \
      | sort \
      | while read -r file ; do
        if [ -d "${file}" ] ; then
            echo "${color_dir}${file}${color_end}"
        elif /bin/grep -q 'set link)' <<< "$file" ; then
            echo " - ${color_link}${file}${color_end}"
        else
            echo " - ${file}"   
        fi
    done    
}
```